# Looking for alternative to pass data between html pages

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

So I am creating an offline web app using appcache.
I need to pass a variable between client and server.
POST is not an option because the server could be offline and appcache will not pull from the cache with a POST request (Explicit or fallback)
GET is not an option because it cannot be cached by appcache because URL is different for each request (?id=n).

Added: I was looking for a way to adapt already created HTML forms (that use POST or GET) for offline use, so a way to store the actual request. Since I could not find a way around the appcache limitations, I ended up rewriting the code to use Indexeddb for storage and service worker fetch interception and background sync methods...much slicker...so long appcache.

Comment: please try something first, and then post your question,

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

> Deprecated
>    This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sessionStorage.

Whenever you want to save data on a page you use the syntax

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name',value);
```

This saves the data offline

and can then be retrieved on any webpage using

```
sessionStorage.getItem('name');
```

This of course only saves the data till the tab is closed / session is ended.. A more permanent method is

```
localStorage
```

... They both use the same format but the latter stores the data even after the browser is closed.